# How to use array_filter with callback in php 5.2

Tags: php, array-filter

I am trying to use array_filter with call back in php 5.2, but I get the following error:

> Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

And I did search the solution using the error in `Google search` and found that `Php 5.2` does not support `callback`.  The code I am working on is:

```
$result = array_filter($lines, function($line) {
  return stripos($line,"ID:")!==false;
});
```

How do I change it so that It can work in `php 5.2`? Any help and workaround would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous functions was introduced in PHP 5.3, so if you are using PHP 5.2 or lower you need to define the function explicitly and pass the functions name as the second argument of `array_filter()`, as shown below.

```
$result = array_filter($lines, 'filter');

function filter($line) {
    return stripos($line,"ID:") !== false;
}
```

Consider upgrading to a newer version of PHP if you can.

- [PHP.net on `array_filter()`](https://php.net/array-filter)
- [PHP.net on anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)
- [PHP.net on the Closure class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php)